# Set initial v-model value when using v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a select that i want to populate with computed data, it works fine:

```
   <select style="width: 175px">
       <option>None</option>
       <option v-for="label in labels">{{label.description}</option>
    </select>

    var vm = new Vue({
            el: '#div',
            data: {
            },
            computed: {
                labels: function () {
                //return labels based on some logic
                }
            }
        });
```

However i want to bind the selected value to a property, so i change my code to:

```
   <select style="width: 175px" v-model=selectedLabel">
       <option>None</option>
       <option v-for="label in labels">{{label.description}</option>
    </select>

    var vm = new Vue({
            el: '#div',
            data: {
              selectedLabel: ''
            },
            computed: {
                labels: function () {
                //return labels based on some logic
                }
            }
        });
```

Then i get no data at all in the select. It's obviously because i set selectedLabel to '', but there is no empty option in my select. But how can i fix this? I don't know what data that will be computed so i can't predefine selectedLabel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the default value of your selection option to `''` like:

```
<div id="app">
  <select style="width: 175px" v-model="selectedLabel">
   <option value="">None</option>
   <option v-for="label in labels" :value="label.value">{{label.description}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This will auto select the `none` option.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gdtm20dx/2/)

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedLabel: ''
  },
  computed: {
    labels: function () {
      return [
        {description:'test', value: 'test'}, 
        {description: 'test1', value: 'test1'}
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select style="width: 175px" v-model="selectedLabel">
   <option value="">None</option>
   <option v-for="label in labels" :value="label.value">{{label.description}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What if i don't want none as an option? If i was to remove it and only set options returned from an API.

Comment: Then your API should tell you which one is selected and you should then set `this.selected` within your code. If you just want it to select the first item then just set `this.selectedLabel = apiArrayList[0].description`